# Several similar Java programs on one virtual box

Tags: java, jvm, virtual-machine

my question is about namespaces in the JVM and how it handles them.
To make the nomenclature in this post a little easier, i refer to Virtual Machines like Virtual Box or VM Ware as virtual boxes, and the Java Virtual Machine as virtual machine.

Say I have a virtual box running on a physical machine. A have a Java runtime installation in this virtual box. Now i run a Java program once in it and leave it running. After that I run the very same Java Program once again. (By running 'java nameoftheProgram', so nothing fancy going on here)
How does the JVM handle the memory areas of those two java programs? Could it happen that the second program interferes with the variables of the first program because both programs are using the same namespace and variable names?

Furthermore, if I had two different Virtual Boxes on the same physical hardware and started one instance of the same java program on each of them, how would they behave?

I ask this question because I have an ongoing discussion about this with a java guru you could say.
He claims even in the second case the two programs interfere with each other because the java programs inside the Virtual boxes use the java virtual machine of the host system.
I respect this guys knowledge and experience, the java noob that I am, but this goes againt every IT-intuition I have. Because normally I would say each program runs in its own process and has its own variables and also own virtual machine and therefore cant mess with the variables of any other process. In the second case I would even say that each virtual box is in its own process with own memory area in its physical box.
If even the second case is true, wouldnt this be a huge security threat? In the web many servers are virtualized and there are several virtual servers of different customers on one physical machine. Couldnt I fiddle around with the variables of a different customer if I found out what java programs are running on his virtual box?
If thats true I think I would find something on the internet about this issue, but I searched for an hour without finding a single source. (the virtual machine vs. java virtual machine doesnt make internet seaches easier though)

Comment: I'd say that your IT-intuition is correct. In both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate processes do not share memory (unless deliberately programmed). You can easily run several JVM’s at the same time as long as the machine has enough resources (cpu/ram/disk etc)

There is however only one process that can bind to a port number on a network interface at a time.  This is why a single web server may have to serve several applications

Comment: thank your for your comment. Yes I know that the programs need to be capable of managing ressources that only exist once, like files, network cards etc. etc.
This question is solely about the programs and their variables.

Comment: Then the answer is "No".

Comment: Note that this is possible in kubernetes.